# Is there a PHP class out there that can clean up content?

Tags: php, regex, string, oop

I have been trying to write in PHP using a series of regular expressions and the PHP function preg_replace.

My main aim is to tidy up the content with things like making sure the beginning of a sentence has an uppercase letter; there is a space after a comma; etc.

Some examples of the tidying I am trying to achieve:

```
// Remove any spaces around slashes
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s*\/\s*/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "/";

// Remove any new lines or tabs
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\r\n\t]/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " ";

// Remove any extra spaces
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s{2,}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " ";

// Tidy up joined full stops
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z]{1})\s*[\.]{1}\s*([^(jpeg|jpg|png|pdf|gif|doc|xls|docx|xlsx|ppt|pptx|html|php|htm)]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1. $2";

// Tidy up joined commas
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s*[\,]{1}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1, $2";

// Tidy up joined exclamation marks
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s*[\!]{1}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1! $2";

// Tidy up joined question marks
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s*[\?]{1}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1? $2";

// Tidy up joined semi colons
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s*[\;]{1}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1; $2";

// Tidy up joined colons
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s*[\:]{1}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1: $2";

// Tidy up fluid ounces
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ff]{1}[Ll]{1}.?\s?[Oo]{1}[Zz]{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "fl oz";

// Tidy up rpm
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Rr]{1}[Pp]{1}[Mm]{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "rpm";

// Tidy up UK
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Uu]{1}[Kk]{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "UK";

// Tidy up Maxi-sense
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Mm]{1}axi[\s\-]?[Ss]{1}ense/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "maxi-sense";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Mm]{1}axi[\s\-]?[Ss]{1}ense/";
$content_replacements_to[] = ". Maxi-sense";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Mm]{1}axi[\s\-]?[Ss]{1}ense/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Maxi-sense";

// Tidy up Side-by-side
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ss]{1}ide[\s\-]?[Bb]{1}y[\s\-]?[Ss]{1}ide/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "side-by-side";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Ss]{1}ide[\s\-]?[Bb]{1}y[\s\-]?[Ss]{1}ide/";
$content_replacements_to[] = ". Side-by-side";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Ss]{1}ide[\s\-]?[Bb]{1}y[\s\-]?[Ss]{1}ide/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Side-by-side";

// Tidy up extra large
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Xx]{1}[Ll]{l}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "extra large";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Xx]{1}[Ll]{l}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Extra large";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Xx]{1}[Ll]{l}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Extra large";

// Tidy up D-radius
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Dd]{1}[\s\-]?[Rr]{1}adius/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "D-radius";

// Tidy up A-rate
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Aa]{1}[\s\-]?[Rr]{1}ate/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "A-rate";

// Tidy up In-column
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ii]{1}n[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}olum[n]?/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "in-column";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Ii]{1}n[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}olum[n]?/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "In-column";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Ii]{1}n[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}olum[n]?/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "In-column";

// Tidy up kW
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Kk]{1}[Ww]{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "kW";

// Tidy up Built-in
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Bb]{1}uilt[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}n/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "built-in";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Bb]{1}uilt[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}n/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Built-in";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Bb]{1}uilt[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}n/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Built-in";

// Tidy up Built-under
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Bb]{1}uilt[\s\-]?[Uu]{1}nder/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "built-under";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Bb]{1}uilt[\s\-]?[Uu]{1}nder/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Built-under";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Bb]{1}uilt[\s\-]?[Uu]{1}nder/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Built-under";

// Tidy up Under-counter
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Uu]{1}nder[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}ounter/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "under-counter";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Uu]{1}nder[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}ounter/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Under-counter";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Uu]{1}nder[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}ounter/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Under-counter";

// Tidy up Under-cabinet
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Uu]{1}nder[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}abinet/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "under-cabinet";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Uu]{1}nder[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}abinet/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Under-cabinet";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Uu]{1}nder[\s\-]?[Cc]{1}abinet/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Under-cabinet";

// Tidy up integrated
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})[\s]{1}[\-]{1}[Ii]{1}ntegrated/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1-integrated";

// Tidy up Semi-integrated
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ss]{1}emi[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}ntegrated/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "semi-integrated";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Ss]{1}emi[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}ntegrated/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Semi-integrated";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Ss]{1}emi[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}ntegrated/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Semi-integrated";

// Tidy up Fully-integrated
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ff]{1}ully[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}ntegrated/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "fully-integrated";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Ff]{1}ully[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}ntegrated/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Fully-integrated";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Ff]{1}ully[\s\-]?[Ii]{1}ntegrated/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Fully-integrated";

// Tidy up Semi-automatic
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ss]{1}emi[\s\-]?[Aa]{1}utomatic/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "semi-automatic";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Ss]{1}emi[\s\-]?[Aa]{1}utomatic/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Semi-automatic";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Ss]{1}emi[\s\-]?[Aa]{1}utomatic/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Semi-automatic";

// Tidy up Fully-automatic
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ff]{1}ully[\s\-]?[Aa]{1}utomatic/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "fully-automatic";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Ff]{1}ully[\s\-]?[Aa]{1}utomatic/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Fully-automatic";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Ff]{1}ully[\s\-]?[Aa]{1}utomatic/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Fully-automatic";

// Tidy up Pull-out
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Pp]{1}ull[\s\-]?[Oo]{1}ut/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "pull-out";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Pp]{1}ull[\s\-]?[Oo]{1}ut/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Pull-out";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Pp]{1}ull[\s\-]?[Oo]{1}ut/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Pull-out";

// Tidy up including
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Ii]{1}nc[l]?[\.]?\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " including ";

// Tidy up use
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Uu]{1}se\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " use ";

// Tidy up ?-piece
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([2345TtYy]{1})[\s\-]?[Pp]{1}iece/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1-piece";

// Tidy up ?-spout
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([Cc]{1})[\s\-]?[Ss]{1}pout/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1-spout";

// Tidy up ?-end
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([Cc]{1})[\s\-]?[Ee]{1}nd/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1-end";

// Tidy up Brushed Steel
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Bb]{1}[\-\/]{1}[Ss]{1}teel/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "brushed steel";

// Tidy up Stainless Steel
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ss]{1}[\-\/]{1}[Ss]{1}teel/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "stainless steel";

// Tidy up Silk Steel
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ss]{1}ilk[\s]?[Ss]{1}teel/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "silk steel";

// Remove trade marks
$content_replacements_from[] = "/™/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "";

// Replace long dashes
$content_replacements_from[] = "/–/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "-";

// Replace single quotes
$content_replacements_from[] = "/’/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "'";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/`/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "'";

// Tidy up m
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\s]?[Mm]{1}etre/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "m";

// Tidy up m3
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([0-9]{1})[\s]?[Mm]{1}3/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1m&sup3;";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\&sup3\;/";
$content_replacements_to[] = html_entity_decode("&sup3;");

// Tidy up to in between numbers
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([0-9]{1})[\s]?to[\s]?([0-9]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1 - $2";

// Tidy up per hour
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Aa]{1}nd\s[Hh]{1}[Rr]?$/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "ph";

// Tidy up l
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\s]?[Ll]{1}itre/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "l";

// Tidy up -in
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\-[Ii]{1}n/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "-in";

// Tidy up plus
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Pp]{1}lus\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " plus ";

// Tidy up including
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Ii]{1}ncluding\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " including ";

// Tidy up including
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Ii]{1}nc\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Including "; 

// Tidy up Push/pull
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[Pp]{1}ush\/[Pp]{1}ull/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "push/pull";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/[\.|\!|\?]{1}\s{1}[Pp]{1}ush\/[Pp]{1}ull/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Push/pull";
$content_replacements_from[] = "/^[Pp]{1}ush\/[Pp]{1}ull/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "Push/pull";

// Tidy up +
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s\+\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " and ";

// Tidy up *
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\*/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "";

// Tidy up with
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Ww]{1}ith\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " with ";

// Tidy up without
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Ww]{1}ithout\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " without ";

// Tidy up in
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Ii]{1}n\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " in ";

// Tidy up of
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Oo]{1}f\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " of ";

// Tidy up for
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Ff]{1}or\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " for ";

// Tidy up or
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Oo]{1}r\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " or ";

// Tidy up and
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Aa]{1}nd\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " and ";

// Tidy up to
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Tt]{1}o\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " to ";

// Tidy up too
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s[Tt]{1}oo\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " too ";

// Tidy up &amp;
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s&amp;\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " and ";

// Tidy up &
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\s&\s/";
$content_replacements_to[] = " and ";

// Tidy up mm
$content_replacements_from[] = "/M[Mm]{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "mm";

// Tidy up ize to ise
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z]{2})ize{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1ise";

// Tidy up izer to iser
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z]{2})izer{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1iser";

// Tidy up yze to yse
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z]{2})yze{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1yse";

// Tidy up ization to isation
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([a-zA-Z]{2})ization{1}/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1isation";

// Tidy up times symbol
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([0-9]{1})\s*[Xx]\s*([0-9A-Za-z]{1})/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1 &times; $2";

// Tidy up times symbol
$content_replacements_from[] = "/\&times\;/";
$content_replacements_to[] = html_entity_decode("&times;");

// Tidy up inches
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([0-9]{1})\s*[Ii]{1}nches/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1\"";

// Tidy up inch
$content_replacements_from[] = "/([0-9]{1})\s*[Ii]{1}nch/";
$content_replacements_to[] = "$1\"";

// Make the replacements
$content = preg_replace($content_replacements_from, $content_replacements_to, $content);
```

This is obviously complicated and lengthy.

Does anyone know a better way of doing it or know of a class that is out there that can do this?

I would then also want to apply this to content within HTML if possible.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the tip. That is a good point.

Comment: Do the regex'es technically work for you or you have a problem with those as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expressions are quite fine for text search and replace. The one's you've been given show that there is room for improvements. But my answer is not about optimizing those, instead I suggest to start building your own set of `StringCleaner` that can do different stuff, but all with the same interface:

```
interface StringCleaner
{
    public function clean($string);
}
```

Next to that, for the HTML, an idea I had is to create an `FilterIterator` that offers access to all text-nodes, so they can be changed with any standard cleaner more easily.

To apply multiple `StringCleaner` at once (and to create sets of those), I used the [Composite Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CompositePattern) (by extending from `SplObjectStore`) that is a `StringCleaner` on it's own as well.

The exmaple w/o the class defintions:

```
$cleanerTrim = new TrimCleaner();

$cleanerBasics = new RegexCleaner();

// Remove any spaces around slashes
$cleanerBasics->addRule('\s*\/\s*', '/');

// Remove any new lines or tabs
$cleanerBasics->addRule('[\r\n\t]', ' ');

// Tidy up joined full stops
$cleanerBasics->addRule('(\w+)\.(?!jpeg|jpg|png|pdf|gif|doc|xls|docx|xlsx|ppt|pptx|html|php|htm)(\w+)', '$1. $2');

// Remove any extra spaces
$cleanerBasics->addRule('\s{2,}', ' ');

// Remove single spaces
$cleanerBasics->addRule('^\s$', '');

$cleanerInches = new RegexCleaner();

// Tidy up inches
$cleanerInches->addRule('([0-9])\s*[Ii]nches', '$1"');


$cleaner = new CleanerComposite();
$cleaner->attach($cleanerBasics);
$cleaner->attach($cleanerInches);
$cleaner->attach($cleanerTrim);


$htmlString = <<<HTML
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
        hello world.hello earth.
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
<table><tr><td>test. 
</td></tr></table>
     <h1>Get it 1 more time.</h1>
     <p>When 12 inches were not enough;      hickup.</p>

  </body>
</html>
HTML;


// load HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

// create XPath
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$it = new DOMTextWhiteSpaceFilter($xpath->query('//text()'));
foreach($it as $node)
{
    $node->data = $cleaner->clean($node->data);
}

// remove whitespace only nodes
$it = new DOMTextWhiteSpaceFilter($xpath->query('//text()'), DOMTextWhiteSpaceFilter::WHITESPACE);
foreach($it as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

As the example already shows, when you hide away the complexity into concrete `StringCleaner` objects, you can start to create more dynamical rules. This can be  extended by adding more `StringCleaner` types that operate on something different than regular expression, a very simple example with `trim` is given in `TrimCleaner`.

But sure, the regular expressions are very powerful, too. As you can see with the `RegexCleaner`, I've moved each regular expressions delimiters into the class itself, so when you define the rules, you don't need to type them over and over again. That's just another simple example where you can simplify things when you encapsulate the replacement into a class of it's own with a defined interface for the action.

[Full Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Es7Kpv).

Comment: Sorry, Hakre I have been offline for a while. Thank you for your detailed answer on this. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way to do this than lots of regexps, but if no-one else can come up with a better tool here is how i'd do it with PHP regexps.

Readability and ease of maintenance are almost always more important than speed. preg_replace does want two separate strings or arrays to match and replace from, but we can deal with that by rearranging our data at the point of use.  So, I would recommend the following more readable format:

```
$content_replacements = array(array('From' => "/pattern 1/", 'To' => "$1 $2"),
                              array('From' => "/pattern 2/", 'To' => "$1,$2."));
```

It has a big advantage that if you forget one 'from' or 'to' you patterns and replacements don't get out of sync.

Then to run all of these you can use a loop:

```
   foreach ($content_replacements as $replacement)
   {
      $content = preg_replace($replacement['From'], $replacement['To'], $content);
   }
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this. I will certainly use this. Do you think I am looking at the wrong thing though. I have since thought about it and do you think I should look for a grammar or spell check type class. Do you know of any?

Comment: @AdamStacey Hi, from my quick look through the manual I think Enchant would do for word by word spell checking.  However for your specific replacements I'm not sure looking at single words will be enough.  I think there must be a better answer out there - I'd be interested in putting a bounty on this in a day if nothing better has surfaced.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first thing you want is to find a good reference on regex and brush up on things like which chars need to be escaped inside and outside of character class (the square brackets: []). Then clean up your regex by removing {1}'s and using case-insensitive match ('//i') when it makes sense. Then I'm including some code that you can use to consolidate some of your capitalization rules, I hope it helps you.

```
// capitalize first word of each sentence
function tidy_sentences($str){
    $tokens = array();
    foreach(preg_split('/([.?!]\s*)/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) as $token){
        if(!preg_match('/([.?!]\s*)/', $token, $m)) $token[0] = strtoupper($token[0]);
        $tokens[] = $token;
    }
    return implode($tokens);
}

// apply capitalization rules to individual words
function tidy_words($str){
    $tokens = array();
    foreach(preg_split('/([^\w-])/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) as $token){
        switch(true){
            // tokens you want to uppercase go here
            case preg_match('/^(uk|kw)$/i', $token, $m): $tokens[] = strtoupper($m[0]); break;
            // tokens you want to lowercase go here
            case preg_match('/^(rpm|fl|oz)$/i', $token, $m): $tokens[] = strtolower($m[0]); break;
            // tokens you want to capitalize first letter go here
            case preg_match('/^(maxi-sense|side-by-side|d-radius)$/i', $token, $m): $tokens[] = ucfirst($m[0]); break;
            default: $tokens[] = $token;
        }
    }
    return implode($tokens);
}

function tidy($str){
    return tidy_sentences(tidy_words($str));
}

echo tidy('foo bar rpm maxi-sense uk Fl OZ baz! pull out');
// => Foo bar rpm Maxi-sense UK fl oz baz! Pull out
```

Comment: Thanks pguardiario, you are right. I do need to brush up on my regex. Thanks for spending time looking into this and all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this isn't necessarily with pure regular expressions.  Regular expressions are meant to be used as a tool to fit strings that follow a pretty specific pattern.  Your use-case here doesn't seem to be that specific, so I think it's time to explore a different avenue.

I'm not sure how complicated the string you're trying to clean is, or what the content typically is (maybe it's typically less than 100 words and pertains to some specific topic, so the common vocabulary is small). However, I think a more flexible (and probably, easier in the long run) solution would involve a much simpler regular expression (or set of regular expressions) to identify tokens in your string.  Once you've identified specific tokens, you can take very specific actions, and perform much more advanced algorithms on your strings, based on the identification tokens.

I believe hakre was on the right path with his StringCleaner class, with the idea of abstracting different types of strings away from your core logic to help clean up your code and make it more manageable and flexible.

I understand this is very generic and theoretical, but the size of the library you're talking about writing will blow up very fast - as it involves (basically) natural language processing, a form of artificial intelligence.

Comment: Thanks Jim, you are right. Regex alone is probably not the right way.